# is there a way to put restrictions on template classes?

Tags: c++, templates

I was just wondering if I can make a template class like so:

`template <class T> void DoSomething(T something);`

but I want to restrict it to only take a float or an int for example.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to use [boost::enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html), which can be used to exclude your template function from being considered depending on the type that T represents. For example,

```
template <class T>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_arithmetic<T>, void>::type DoSomething(T t);
```

Would restrict your template function to integral and floating-point types.

Comment: Or, if you're using C++11, it's got `std::enable_if` which is basically the same.

Comment: so what would you do for is char array?

Comment: @AlexKorban My understanding is that `std::enable_if` actually functions the same as `boost::enable_if_c`, so you would need `std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, void>`.

Comment: @Pittfall to test if T is a char[], one would do `boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_array<T>::value && boost::is_same<boost::remove_extant<T>::type, char>::value>` (or `std::enable_if<std::is_array<T>::value && std::is_same<std::remove_extant<T>::type, char>::value>`) remove_extant strips away the last array subscript, if any, from the type.

Comment: I should add that to restrict to a specific type such as char[], an overload is probably a better option. enable_if is most useful when you want to accept multiple types that all meet a specific criteria. For example, if you wanted to accept an array of any integral type: `boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_array<T>::value && boost::is_integral<boost::remove_extant<T>::type>::value>`

Answer (score 1):

yes, Take a look at template specialization. here- http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.7

Comment: Specialization won't restrict the type of input.  It specializes based on the input.

Comment: yes, you could provide specialization for float or int or whatever type you want and for types that you don't want you would just have default implementation which could be to do nothing. I hope i am making some sense?

Comment: With this method, at best you could make it throw an exception at run-time for non-arithmetic types. It's better to check this at compile time, as rkjnsn suggests in his answer.

Comment: @AlexKorban If you don't define the default implementation then builds will fail. But if the only valid instantiations of a function template are specialized versions then you're usually better of with just overloading.

Comment: What is the difference between specialization and overloading then?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just overload the function for all supported types. This produces more code than using `(boost|std)::enable_if`.

Answer (score 0):

In the six years since this was asked, things have improved somewhat!  I’ll post a brief update.

➽ `std::enable_if` can be used in a third place now, which gets rid of the issue with some functions simply not having a place in the signature to stick it.  This is to use trailing dummy template arguments.

```
public:
    template<typename R ,
        typename = std::enable_if_t<is_range_t<R>::value>  >
    Fizzer_t (const R& range_of_itemdefs);
```

➽ The introduction of `alias templates` means you don’t need `template`⋯`::type` everywhere!  That alone is a big improvement.  They also make it easier to bundle up constraints to reuse them or simply detail them elsewhere than the constrained function’s signature.

➽ *Expression* SFINAE, and `declspec`, means you can easily just show the kind of code syntax you want to work and reject the function if that’s not so.

➽ Training return types work in conjunction with this, so you can use the arguments of the function *together* and have a place to put the SFINAE expression to sniff out its validity.

➽ The above, plus some stuff that’s been figured out already and packaged up in library/idiom form gives us more idiomatic (this readable) constraining, including the [*detection idiom*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

➽ `constexpr` has been called a game-changer for template metaprogramming in general.  You don’t need to use metafunctions to do simple arithmetic.

➽ The `if constexper` construct can eliminate the need for writing such constraints as part of overloading!

➽ If you want to be on the bleeding edge, [*Concepts Lite*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) are nearly ready and are experimental in some compilers now.  Other solutions exist to emulate most of it in a systematic manner.